# predictive analytics 1year - R

Tags: r, arima, predictive-models

Hi I am using R to create a predictive analysis, my issue is that a just have 24 periods (2 years) of data an I need to predict 1year. The ARIMA only bring me the first numbers of my model, which is the recomendation for seasonal and period values? or which is the best way to predict with less historical data?

ARIMA(0,1,0)

sigma^2 estimated as 98923901: log likelihood=-244.35 AIC=490.7 AICc=490.89 BIC=491.83

```
datos<-read.csv("Predict.csv",header=T,dec=",",sep=";")
head(beer)
dim(datos)
beer<-ts(datos[,1],start=c(2019,1),freq=12)

auto.arima(datos)

mod<-arima(beer,order=c(0,1,0),seasonal=list(order=c(?,?,?),period=?))
pred<-predict(mod,n.ahead=2)
pred
```

Regards